# What is the reference that need to be added for "using Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth" to get facebook authentication?

Tags: c#

Here is the codes that gives errors.

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
   appId: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppId"],
   appSecret: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppSecret"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an ASP.NET addon thingy. You can get it via NuGet:

```
PM > Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth
```

Answer (score 1):

try "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth" in your nuget console.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth/